# Deploy php project on localhost

Tags: php, winginx

I'm trying to deploy php project on localhost using [Winginx](http://winginx.com/en/)

Now poking around this php code

```
public static function compareIP( $ip, $mask )
{
    $arr1 = ( ".", $ip );
    $arr2 = ( ".", $mask );
    $good = true;
    $i = 0;
    while ( $i < ( $arr1 ) )
    {
        if ( $arr2[$i] != "*" && $arr2[$i] != $arr1[$i] )
        {
            $good = false;
            break;
        }
        ++$i;
    }
    return $good;
}
```

Server returns

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\Winginx\home\site.com\index.php on line 54
```

Where line 54 is

```
$arr1 = ( ".", $ip );
```

I'm new to php and just want  to deploy project, but google didn't give any hints.

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: I think PHP uses `[]` for array literals, not `()`. Also, why are you using those inner parentheses in this line? `while ( $i < ( $arr1 ) )`

Comment: Are you missing `array` ? `$arr1 = array( ".", $ip );`

Comment: @SubirKumarSao, thx. Seems like this eliminates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I allowed myself to correct your code and tidying it a bit. Your main problem was that you were missing the array definition before putting the elements into the array. Also, in your while function you should say while `$i` is less than `count( $arr )`, as this returns the number of elements in the array in a numeric format.

```
public static function compareIP( $ip, $mask ){
    $arr1 = array( ".", $ip );
    $arr2 = array( ".", $mask );
    $good = true;
    $i = 0;
    while ( $i < count( $arr ) )
    {
        if ( $arr2[$i] != "*" && $arr2[$i] != $arr1[$i] ){
            $good = false;
            break;
        }
        ++$i;
    }
    return $good;
}
```